# Show the expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ Let $S_n=\frac{(X_1+\cdots+X_n)}{n}$ and $V_n=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-S_n)^2$. Show that $E(S_n) =\mu$ and $E(V_n)=\sigma^2$

Would the variance be tackled something like this:

$\operatorname{Var}(X)= \operatorname{E}(X-\operatorname{E}(X))^2$ then $\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-S_n)^2)}{n-1}\right) = \operatorname{E}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-S_n)^2}{n-1}\right)-\operatorname{E}\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-S_n)^2)}{n-1}\right)^2$

Comment: You mean $var(V_n)$?

Comment: This prrof is almost everywhere. You can find a proof for example in (http://www.utdallas.edu/~serfling/handouts/ExpValSampVar.pdf). It is linked to the unbiased variance estimator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that $E(S_n) = \mu$. To see $E(V_n)=\sigma^2$,
$$ \begin{align}
E(X_i - S_n)^2 &= E(X_i^2 + S_n^2 -2X_i S_n) \\
&= E(X_i^2) + E(S_n^2)-2E(X_iS_n) \quad \cdots (1)
\end{align}
$$ 
Since $E(X_i^2) = \mu^2 +\sigma^2$ and $E(S_n^2) = \mu^2 + n^{-1}\sigma^2$, we have 
$$
\begin{align}
(1) &= 2\mu^2 + (1+\frac{1}{n})\sigma^2 - \frac{2}{n}E\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_iX_k \right) \\
&= 2\mu^2 + (1+\frac{1}{n})\sigma^2 - \frac{2}{n}\left[\sum_{k=1, k\neq i}^n \big(E(X_i)E(X_k)\big) + E(X_i^2)\right] \\
&=2\mu^2 + (1+\frac{1}{n})\sigma^2-\frac{2}{n}\left((n-1)\mu^2 + \mu^2 +\sigma^2 \right) \\
&= (1-\frac{1}{n})\sigma^2. 
\end{align}
$$
Thus, 
$$
\begin{align}
E(V_n) &= \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n} E(X_i-S_n)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1} n (1-\frac{1}{n})\sigma^2 \\
&=\sigma^2.
\end{align}$$

---

Since $X_i, 1\leq i \leq n$ are uncorrelated, $var(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n var(X_i).$ So,

$$
\begin{align}
var(S_n)&=\frac{1}{n^2} var\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} var(X_i) \\
&= \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $E(S_n^2) = E(S_n)^2 + var(S_n) = \mu^2 + n^{-1} \sigma^2.$

Comment: Please show how you work out $E(S_n^2) = \mu^2+n^{-1}\sigma^2$.

Comment: @Veliko Okay, I will add that.

Comment: would showing $E(S_n)=\mu$ be a similar process?

Comment: @Killer, this is just linearity of expectation: $E(S_n) = E(\dfrac{X_1+\ldots+X_n)}{n}) = \dfrac{1}{n}(E(X_1) + \ldots + E(X_n)) = \dfrac{n\mu}{n} = \mu$.

Comment: can you explain how $E(X_1)+..+E(X_n)= n\mu$ just trying to see the picture. Thank you

Comment: @Killer $X_i$ are identically distributed, so their expectations are..

Comment: @Killer, i.i.d random variables, as you wrote in the problem statement means that all $X_i$ have the same mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Thus $E(X_1) + \ldots + E(X_n) = \mu + \ldots + \mu = n\mu$.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have $$n^2E(S_n^2) = E(\sum X_i^2 + 2\sum X_iX_j) = \sum EX_i^2 + 2\sum EX_iEX_j = \sum(\sigma^2+\mu^2) +2\sum \mu^2 = n\sigma^2 + n\mu^2 + n(n-1)\mu^2 = n\sigma^2 + n^2\mu^2.$$

Then $ES_n^2 = \mu^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2.$

Note that $(X_i-\mu)^2 = (X_i-S_n)^2 + (S_n-\mu)^2 + 2(X_i-S_n)(S_n-\mu)$. Then $$\sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i-\mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i-S_n)^2 + nE(S_n-\mu)^2$$ 
$$n\sigma^2 = E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-S_n)^2\right) + n(ES_n^2-\mu^2)$$
$$n\sigma^2 = (n-1)EV_n + \sigma^2$$
$$EV_n = \sigma^2.$$